# Unable to load wsdl link in soap ui

Tags: web-services, testing, soap, soapui

Any buddy know how to resolve this issue.

Soap ui is not able to load WSDL link.

Please check the attached image. and let me the solution please.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a proxy/firewall problem.  See if you can get that WSDL to load in a web browser. If so, check to see if your web browser is configured to use a proxy.  I bet it is. In that case, you will need to use the same proxy setup in SoapUI.

Comment: "Use system proxy settings" is selected in browser

Comment: So you may need to configure SoapUI to use the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i start using "Advance Rest client" addon of chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get that `WSDL` to load without issue.

In SoapUI, go to:

1. File
2. New SoapUI project
3. Enter a project name
4. Paste the URL in the 'Initial WSDL/WADL' field
5. Click 'Ok'.

NOTE:  I was able to do this using SoapUI Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue, it probably happened by firewall/proxy configuration issue.

1. Go to SoapUi Vmoptions in bin folder on *Program files*
2. Edit in notepad and add these below command to Vm options

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2

And save it, then restart entire soap UI application.

Answer (score 0):

First try to open that wsdl in a browser if you are able to open it there then you should be able to open it in soapUI. You should also check if there is any proxy being used on the browser or you have an incorrect proxy setup in soapUI.

I am able to open this url on my broswer and import it in soapUI.

I have downloaded the WSDL file which you should be able to use in soapUI to create a project without any issues. Check the link below, it will be available for 2 days.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7mJBdNSSV-YWTdIXzYwcTJDaWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: "Use system proxy settings" is selected in browser

Comment: Try to setup that proxy in soapUI and see if that makes it work. Have you downloaded the wsdl file i shared, I want to close that link. Are you still getting the error?